# speech recognition onresult called twice on mobile and tablet deveices

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, webspeech-api

I am trying to create a speech recognition enabled web application. I have successfully implemented the same and its working as expected on the desktop. But On mobile and tablet devices the onResult called twice and the second result is what i expected not the first. But because of this I couldn't get the result as I expected. Is anyone facing the same issue let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood your issue, and by my understanding you seem to be having an issue with extracting web-speech recognition results correctly on mobile devices.

The native speech recognition, most notably, chrome/android browsers on Android, handle speech recognition results slightly differently from their desktop versions. Recognition results where `isFinal` is true, are usually complete sentences, recognized by the mobile browsers, where as, for example, on desktop chrome, even words are returned with `isFinal==true`.

Here's a simplified version of what worked best for me.

```
var mobile=false;
if(/*Use preferred method to detect mobile device*/){
   mobile=true;
}
Recognizer.onresult = function(event){
  var interimTranscripts = '';
  var finalTranscripts = '';
  for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
    var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
    if(event.results[i].isFinal){
      if(mobile){  //if running on a mobile device
        finalTranscripts = transcript;
      }else{
        finalTranscripts += transcript;
      }
    }else{
      if(mobile){  //if running on a mobile device
        interimTranscripts = transcript;
      }else{
        interimTranscripts += transcript;
      }
    }
  }
  if(finalTranscripts){
    target.value = finalTranscripts; //the output
    if(!mobile){
      Recognition.stop();
    }
  }
  else if(interimTranscripts){
    target.value = interimTranscripts + finalTranscripts;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I also found I needed to ignore SpeechRecognitionAlternative entries where `.confidence === 0` to get it to work on Chrome Android. Full code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77046406/392622