# Speech Recognition result double in mobile

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I have tried this code work fine on pc desktop windows. But this not work on mobile devices, they result multiple sentences on textarea.

```
speechRecognition.onresult = (event) => {
  var teks_transkrip= "";
   var transkrip_akhir = "";
      // Ulangi hasil dari objek pengenalan suara.
    for (let i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
      if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
        transkrip_akhir+= event.results[i][0].transcript;
      } else {
        teks_transkrip+= event.results[i][0].transcript;
        $("#pratinjau").val(teks_transkrip);
      }}  
    $("#artikel").insertIntoTextArea(transkrip_akhir);
    transkrip_akhir = "";
  };

$.fn.insertIntoTextArea = function(textToInsert) {
   var data = $("#artikel").val();
   if (textToInsert.trim() == "titik"){
     $("#artikel").val(data + ".");
     return;
   }
     if (textToInsert.trim() == "baris baru"){
     $("#artikel").val(data + "\n");
     return;
   }
   
        if (textToInsert.trim() == "paragraf baru"){
     $("#artikel").val(data + "\n\n");
     return;
   }
   
     if (textToInsert.trim() == "titik koma"){
     $("#artikel").val(data + ";");
     return;
   }
   
    if (textToInsert.trim() == "koma"){
     $("#artikel").val(data + ",");
     return;
   }
   
   $("#artikel").val(data + textToInsert);
}
```

I've read this article [speech recognition onresult called twice on mobile and tablet deveices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001942/speech-recognition-onresult-called-twice-on-mobile-and-tablet-deveices) and it doesn't help at all.

i want speech reccognition worked on al devices that using chrome

Answer (score 0):

There are a few quirks. The following is working well for me on Chrome on Android, Chrome & Safari on iPad, and Chrome on Windows desktop:

```
for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
  if (event.results[i].isFinal && event.results[i][0].confidence !== 0) {
    final_transcript = (isMobileOrTablet ? "" : final_transcript) + event.results[i][0].transcript;
  } else {
    interim_transcript = (isMobileOrTablet ? "" : interim_transcript) + event.results[i][0].transcript;
  }
}
```

With this mobile/tablet check from https://gist.github.com/tallesairan/62de15a3b3d1f3da3412f2af82aa20f8:

```
function mobileAndTabletCheck() {
  let check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino|android|ipad|playbook|silk/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
};
let isMobileOrTablet = mobileAndTabletCheck()
```

(That regex might be overkill but it's working for now.)

Basically, isFinal behaves differently on mobile, as identified by [this answer to that related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001942/speech-recognition-onresult-called-twice-on-mobile-and-tablet-deveices), but I also found that multiple firings were still giving me issues. Considering any SpeechRecognitionAlternative entries with confidence of zero as interim rather than final seems to solve it.